# Foldl vs Foldr memory usage

Tags: haskell, fold

Given the Fibonacci infinite list

```
fibo a b = a : fibo b (a+b)
```

And given the two following calls:

- `foldl (+) 1 (take 1000000 $ fibo 1 1)`
- `foldr (+) 1 (take 1000000 $ fibo 1 1)`

I expected the first one (foldl) to allocate a huge amount of memory because of thunks and in fact that's what happens.

However, I didn't expect the same for the second one. Because of how the foldr is defined I thought a usual stack like evaluation would have been performed for the right argument of (+) (because of its strictness).

Actually even in this case I have a huge amount of memory that is allocated.

What is happening?

Comment: The best function for doing that particular task efficiently is `foldl'`. It's *possible* to do it efficiently using `foldr`, but only in a somewhat twisted fashion: `foldr (\x r acc -> r $! x + acc) id (take ...) 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foldr f z xs` is inefficient when `f` is strict on its second argument (like `(+)`), since it evaluates to

```
f1 x1 (f x2 (f x3 ...
```

and this can not start to evaluate until the very end of the list. If `f` were not strict on the second argument, evaluation could instead start sooner.